# ChickenScheme Spock JavaScript Compiler installation issue

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, scheme, chicken-scheme

Trying to install and run [Spock](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/spock) (extension of [ChickenScheme](http://wiki.call-cc.org/) ).

At first, I even don't know this depends on ChickenScheme framework, but I manage to install and run ChickenScheme

```
$ Chicken      
(c) 2008-2013, The Chicken Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.8.0.1 (stability/4.8.0) (rev 54c391c)
macosx-unix-clang-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
compiled 2013-01-17 on aeryn.xorinia.dim (Darwin)
```

and [eggs](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggs), where I guessed the egg must be spock according to **Installing eggs**

```
$ chicken-install spock
retrieving ...
```

After the completion of the installaton, I tried http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/spock#using-the-static-compiler

```
$ chicken-spock
zsh: command not found: chicken-spock

$ chicken-spock -help
zsh: command not found: chicken-spock
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Not sure there are many Chicken users here. Did you try on their mailing list? it's quite active.

Comment: I don't understand why chicken scheme installation questions end up being closed as off topic to superuser, since ultimately the community that actually cares about installing a scheme programming language is on SO...

Comment: Unfriendly Community. One of the worst experiment to install some framework.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that chicken does not have the necessary permissions to install properly:

```
$ chicken-install spock
retrieving ...
cp -r jsmin.so /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/jsmin.so
cp: /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/jsmin.so: Permission denied
Error: shell command failed with nonzero exit status 256:
  cp -r jsmin.so /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/jsmin.so
Error: shell command terminated with nonzero exit code 17920

$ chicken-spock
-bash: chicken-spock: command not found
```

After receiving the same error, the following works:

```
$ sudo chicken-install spock
```

The installation can be verified with the following commands:

```
$chicken-status -list
(chicken-spock "0.091")
(jsmin "2.1")
(make "1.7")
(matchable "3.3")
(spock "0.091")

$ chicken-status spock
chicken-spock ................................................. version: 0.091
spock ......................................................... version: 0.091
```

Or to see a list of library files:

```
$ chicken-status -f
/opt/local/bin/chicken-spock
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/jsmin.import.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/jsmin.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/make.import.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/make.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/matchable.import.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/matchable.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/spock
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/spock-compiler.import.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/spock-compiler.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/spock.import.so
/opt/local/lib/chicken/6/spock.so
```